# Implementing Maven for an existing project

Tags: java, maven, project, dependency-management

I have a project implemented in ADF.

I need to build it using Maven now.

I wrote the POM but now stuck at adding dependancies.

There are way too many JAR files, specifically about ADF, Toplink etc which I believe I will need to put in my POM.

Now, only way till now i could figure out is to go to each JAR, open manifest file, get version etc, and then get the dependancy block from maven online repository.

Is there a diff and easier and faster way of doing it.

Please help!!

Note: Chances are high that my question may sound illogical or stupid cause I have been using maven only for a week now.

-Santosh

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a decend IDE, it could resolve your dependencies for you. If it can't import a class, you can ask it to look up the class in the Maven repository. Then you can choose which dependency to add to your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using JDeveloer. Would it have this facility?